# Como utilizar AsyncTask no Android?

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando fazer meu aplicativo baixar um XML (RSS Feed) e ler suas tags para exibi-lo na tela inicial. Porém o aplicativo fecha após realizar o download antes de tentar iniciar o método *onPostExecute* do AsyncTask **getFeed** (Baixar o XML) e o AsyncTask **lerXML** (Leitura das Tags). E caso eu tente apenas checar a versão do aplicativo, eu utilizo o AsyncTask para baixaro arquivo e ler seu conteúdo, checar a versão e perguntar ao usuário se ele deseja realizar a atualização do aplicativo. Só que, se eu já executei o AsyncTask **atualizaApp**, eu não posso executar o **baixaAPK** sem que o aplicativo feche.

Código completo: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rTNtEFyu)

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> getFeed = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String retorno = "não";
            try {
                // Baixar Feed
                URL url = new URL("http://www.ipoema.tumblr.com/rss");
                File file = new File(PATH + "iPoema.xml");
                file.delete();
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                lenghtOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();
                int current = 0;
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
                    progress = current;
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                fos.close();
                retorno = "sim";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                showMessage(e.getClass().getName(), "Erro ao tentar realizar o download do arquivo.");
            }
            return retorno;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (s.equals("sim")) {
                try {
                    lerXML.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showMessage(e.getClass().getName(), "Erro ao tentar realizar a leitura do arquivo.");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> lerXML = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String state = "erro";
            try {
                // Ler XML
                showMessage("iPoema", "Arquivo lido com sucesso");
                File f = new File(PATH + "iPoema.xml");
                SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
                Document d = sb.build(f);
                Element mural = d.getRootElement();
                List<Element> elements = mural.getChildren("channel");
                Iterator<Element> i = elements.iterator();
                int x = 0;
                //for (int x = 0; x <= elements.size(); x++) {
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    //Element node = (Element) elements.get(x);
                    Element node = (Element) i.next();
                    Element item = node.getChild("item");

                    titulo[x] = item.getChildText("title");
                    texto[x] = item.getChildText("description");
                    autor[x] = item.getChildText("category");
                    x++;
                }
                state = "ok";
            } catch (JDOMException e) {
                showMessage(e.getClass().getName(), "Erro ao tentar realizar a leitura do XML.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                showMessage(e.getClass().getName(), "Erro ao tentar realizar a leitura do XML.");
            }
            return state;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (s.equals("ok")) {
                try {
                    // Títulos
                    TextView titulo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo1);
                    TextView titulo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo2);
                    TextView titulo3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo3);
                    TextView titulo4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo4);

                    // Textos
                    TextView texto1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto1);
                    TextView texto2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto2);
                    TextView texto3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto3);
                    TextView texto4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto4);

                    // SetText
                    titulo1.setText(getTitulo(0));
                    texto1.setText(getTexto(0)+"\n\n#"+getAutor(0)+"\n\n");

                    titulo2.setText(getTitulo(1));
                    texto2.setText(getTexto(1)+"\n\n#"+getAutor(1)+"\n\n");

                    titulo3.setText(getTitulo(2));
                    texto3.setText(getTexto(2)+"\n\n#"+getAutor(2)+"\n\n");

                    titulo4.setText(getTitulo(3));
                    texto4.setText(getTexto(3)+"\n\n#"+getAutor(3)+"\n\n");

                    // Exibe
                    titulo1.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                    texto1.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

                    titulo2.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                    texto2.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

                    titulo3.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                    texto3.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

                    titulo4.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                    texto4.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showMessage(e.getClass().getName(), "Erro ao tentar realizar a leitura do arquivo.");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> atualizaApp = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String versao = "0";
            try {
                // Baixar iPoema.txt
                URL url = new URL("http://www.xadees.xpg.com.br/iPoema.txt");
                File file = new File(PATH + "iPoema.txt");
                file.delete();
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                lenghtOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();
                int current = 0;
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
                    progress = current;
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                fos.close();

                // Ler iPoema.txt
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                }
                versao = text.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                showMessage(e.getClass().getName(), "Erro ao tentar realizar o download do arquivo.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showMessage(e.getClass().getName(), "Erro ao tentar realizar a leitura do arquivo.");
            }

            return versao;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            int vAtual = Pi.versionCode;
            int vAPK = Integer.parseInt(s);

            if (vAtual < vAPK) {
                try {
                    // Baixar
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.xadees.xpg.com.br/iPoema%20for%20Android.apk");
                    File file = new File(PATH + "iPoema.apk");
                    file.delete();
                    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                    lenghtOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();
                    int current = 0;
                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                        baf.append((byte) current);
                        progress = current;
                    }
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                    fos.close();

                    // Instalar
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH + "iPoema.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    //java.lang.Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "adb install -r " + PATH + "iPoema.apk"});
                    //proc.waitFor();
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    showMessage(e.getClass().getName(), "Erro ao tentar realizar o download do pacote.");
                }
            } else {
                showMessage("iPoema", "iPoema já está atualizado.");
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Para atualizar **APK**, aconselho que use as APIs do Google Play. E não sei o que seu metódo `showMessage` está fazendo, mais se for algo que envolva `UI`, é ali que pode estár havendo a parada do aplicativo, pois no metódo `doInBackground` de um `AsyncTask` você não pode acessar a `UI`

Comment: Seu logcat apresenta alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Ahh, showMessage é um metodo para exibir uma MessageBox. Vou retirá-la e testar. E eu não utilizo logcat, ou pelo menos eu não sei ver.

Comment: Eu não sei se o que eu vou dizer faz sentido, até aonde entendi o seu aplicativo fecha "sozinho", ou nem chega a abrir na segunda vez (ou após o update), é isso? Se for eu suponho que o "Thread" esteja "travado" (não sei como explicar de maneira técnica) e por isso não consegue recriar o "processo", pois ele está ocupado, veja se isto ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44480/3635

Answer (score 2):

Olhando rapidamente para o seu código, percebi que você inicializa todas as `AsyncTasks` em uma *Thread* separada.

`AsyncTasks` são rotinas que facilitam a utilização de Threads no Android. Elas executam um código em background*(nova thread)*, na chamada `doInBackground` e são capazes de realizar mudanças na *thread* de UI na chamada `onPostExecute`.

Desta forma, o seu código apresenta dois problemas:

-Criar uma nova *thread* para chamar uma `asyncTask`, o que não é necessário, e pode gerar problemas.
-Modificações realizadas no processo `doInBackground`, quando deveriam ser realizadas apenas no `onPostExecute`

Além disso, tenha em mente que o Android limita o número de `asyncTasks` que podem rodar em paralelo. Apenas 1 para **android 3.0** em diante

Comment: Eu percebi que não posso rodar a mesma *AsyncTask* mais de uma vez ou então o aplicativo fecha sem exibir nada. E eu utilizo uma *AsyncTask* para baixar o **iPoema.txt** e ler a versão do apk, que depois ele chama outra *AsyncTask*, pois eu tentei utilizar no próprio *onPostExecute*, mas o aplicativo fechava se eu tentasse baixar o arquivo. E mesmo retirando o showMessage, nada mudou.

Answer (score 1):

O que o Felipe quis dizer seria criar uma interface e fazer sua Activity implementar essa interface, e ao criar a instância da Asynctask passar a referência da sua activity à ela (sua classe Asynctask deve ter uma referência ao objeto da interface), dessa forma no método onPostExecute vc chama o método implementado pela sua activity passando o parâmetro (se houver). Dessa forma vc estaria fazendo as threads "se comunicarem".

Eu utilizo dessa forma e nunca tive problema.

Answer (score 0):

SEMPRE separe as "responsabilidades" de cada ação! Crie duas classes distintas para AsyncTask.

Lembre-se, AsynkTask é uma thread separada da Thread principal.

Para você receber o retorno da tua Async, você pode criar uma Interface com método OnResult(Boolean result) e implementar na Activity que a chama, para dai sim fazer a nova chamada da sua outra AsyncTask.

Comment: Por favor, poderia me explicar melhor? Ainda fiquei com dúvidas do que fazer. Estou pensando em seguir o que @debeka disse, mas quero entender o que você disse para tentar alguma coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, não entendi muito bem o que vc fez, mas um possível solução seria o seguinte código :

Cria uma class para fazer o que vc quer e extends AsyncTask, já que  vc só pode executar um de cada  vez.

```
private class NomeDaClass extends AsyncTask {

    private  int tipoDeFuncao ;

    public NomeDaClasse(int a) {
       this.tipoDeFuncao = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

      if (typeofFunction == 1) {
        atualizaApp();
      } else if (typeofFunction == 2) {
        lerXML();
      } else if (typeofFunction == 3) {
        getFeed();
      }

      return null;
    }

}
```

Então, na sua classe normal, você cria as funções que vc quer executar em background e dentro delas você chama o construtor da sua classe que herda de AsyncTask:

```
public void atualizaApp() {    
    new Connection(1).execute();
}

public void lerXML(parameters) {
    new Connection(2).execute();

}

public void getFeed(parameters) {
    new Connection(3).execute();

}
```

Não é o melhor, mas é uma solução. :)