# Tarefa com AsyncTask só executa uma vez, depois não chega no doInBackground

Tags: android, async

Estou enfrentando um problema estranho na minha aplicação, já que em estou testando em 4 dispositivos diferentes mas só dois deles tem o comportamento esperado.

Cenário / Dispositivos:

- Nexus 4 / Android 5.0 - **Ok**
- Galaxy Tab 2 / Android 4.2.2 - **Ok**
- LG Optimus / Android 4.4.2 - **Erro**
- Genesis / Android 4.1.2 - **Erro**

Como podem ver, **4 versões do Android** diferente e somente nas duas primeiras está funcionando.

O problema em questão é que no primeiro momento que eu instalo o aplicativo no dispositivo, executo uma tarefa com `AsyncTask` e ocorre tudo normalmente. Mas a partir daí eu não consigo executar mais nenhuma vez.

Como o método `onPreExecute()` é executado ainda na mesma thread, meu *debug* chega nele sem problema, mas não no `doInBackground()`.

Li algo sobre o método `executeOnExecutor()` a partir da API 11 (meu aplicativo é a partir da 15) mas não acho que é o caso, já que eu não quero várias tarefas em paralelo e sim uma simples.

A representação simples do meu código é esta:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Preparo minha UI
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Executo minha tarefa
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Conclusão
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}.execute();
```

Enfim, não sei o pode estar acontecendo, já pesquisei bastante e não achei nada. Meu ambiente de desenvolvimento é o **Android Studio 1.0.1**, compilado com a versão 21 do SDK.

Comment: Só uma duvida, aonde exatamente você chama o `.execute()`? Seria dentro de um `onClick` ou no `onCreate`?

Comment: Tenho tarefas no `onCreate` da *ativity* e `onClick` de um botão também, mas em todas elas o mesmo problema ocorre, após funcionar a primeira vez depois de uma instalação, não funciona mais.

Comment: Você quer dizer que você utiliza o mesmo `AsyncTask` para várias tarefas? Deixe-me ver se entendi, supondo que você tenha criado um evento `onCreate` e ele chame o `AsyncTask`, se clicar a primeira vez funciona, mas se clicar a segunda não funciona? Ou você quer dizer que ele só funciona na primeira instalação?

Comment: Outra duvida, você realmente necessita usar `return null;` em um metodo que usa `Void`?

Comment: Não é o mesmo `AsyncTask` pois para cada um eu crio uma nova instância. Tenho uma tarefa de encontrar a localização no `onCreate` da *activity* e um botão para enviar essa localização por exemplo. Na primeira instalação, a primeira tarefa de encontrar a localização funciona. Depois eu não consigo finalizar nem a tarefa do `onCreate` novamente e nem clicar no botão. De alguma forma a *thread* parece que está sendo ocupada, impedindo de executar outras, mas não faço ideia de como está acontecendo isso, como você pode ver, meu código é bem simples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PauloRodrigues acredito que por não estar "vinculado" `Thread` principal talvez o processo esteja ocupado. Uma maneira de fazer seria "estender" o `AsyncTask` em sua classe principal.

Outra coisa que notei é que você usou `return null;` em uma método que retorna `Void`, acredito que isto não seja o correto (ou necessário) e você também usou Void em um tipo de metodo, geralmente seria "lowercase" (letra minuscula):

`protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {`

O código deve ficar tipo isto:

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends Activity {
    ...

    public void onClick(View view){
            new meuMetodo().execute();
    }

    private class meuMetodo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ....
        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Executo minha tarefa
        }
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Guilherme, transferi todos os `new AsyncTask...` que eu fazia diretamente nas minhas chamadas para uma classe estendida de `AsyncTask` e funcionou. Não entendo porque isso aconteceu, eu achei que não fosse necessário ter uma classe só para fazer em outra *thread*, e mais estranho, em 4 versões do Android houve comportamentos distintos.

Comment: Em relação ao outro ponto, não é possível passar `void` na classe `AsyncTask`, logo, não consigo fazer que o retorno de `doInBackground()` seja `void` por isso do objeto Void e o retorno nulo, nunca tive problema. Mas enfim, a sua primeira dica já resolveu meu problema. Obrigado!

Comment: @PauloRodrigues acredito que o `AsyncTask` necessite da classe principal para receber os "sinais" do "Active". Que bom que deu certo, sucesso no seu projeto!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tente não usar o mesmo objeto para cada execução.

Toda vez que você for executar suia AsyncTask, instancie um novo objeto.

Acredito que dessa forma vai funcionar normalmente.

Já tive problemas semelhantes e, pesquisando, resolvi dessa forma.

Não faça isso:

```
 AsyncTask obj = new AsyncTask();

    obj.execute();

Depois novamente ...


 obj.execute();
```

Toda vez que for executar, faça:

```
new AsyncTask().execute();
```

Considerando os devidos parâmetros para seu caso.