# HttpURLConnection retornando vazio

Tags: java, android

Mensagem

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Chamada

> ```
> JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));
> ```

Código:

```
public static String getHttpGet(String url) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            URL myurl = new URL("http://www.exemplo.com.br/gerajson.php");
            HttpURLConnection urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
            urlconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlconnection.connect();
            InputStream is = urlconnection.getInputStream();
            if (is != null) {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is));
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } finally {
                    is.close();
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Atualização (ao trocar-se o conteúdo do `catch`):

> app has stopped. br.com.webvisionsistemas.shishamaps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: br.com.webvisionsistemas.shishamaps, PID: 2561 java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at br.com.webvisionsistemas.shishamaps.MapaFragment.getHttpGet(‌​MapaFragment.java:17‌​6) at br.com.webvisionsistemas.shishamaps.MapaFragment.onMapReady(‌​MapaFragment.java:64‌​)

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) { result = null; }` - Isto daqui não é uma boa ideia, você está engolindo o erro real para mascará-lo como um `NullPointerException` depois. Se você trocar esse `result = null;` por um `e.printStackTrace(); throw new RuntimeException(e);`, o que aparece?

Comment: app has stopped.

br.com.webvisionsistemas.shishamaps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: br.com.webvisionsistemas.shishamaps, PID: 2561                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at br.com.webvisionsistemas.shishamaps.MapaFragment.getHttpGet(MapaFragment.java:176)
                                                                                       at br.com.webvisionsistemas.shishamaps.MapaFragment.onMapReady(MapaFragment.java:64)

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro problema é esse trecho:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = null;
    }
```

Isto daqui não é uma boa ideia, pois vai engolir o erro real para mascará-lo como um `NullPointerException` depois. Trocando-se o `result = null;` por isso:

```
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

A exceção gerada é diferente (conforme o seu comentário). A exceção passa a ser `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Como o nome da exceção indica, você está tentando executar operações de rede (download via internet) na thread principal. Se isso fosse permitido, iria acabar deixando o seu aplicativo congelado por algum tempo enquanto a operação é executada, o que resultaria em uma péssima experiência ao usuário e um aplicativo não-responsivo. Por esse motivo, não é permitido realizar esse tipo de operação na thread principal.

Assim sendo, a solução é invocar o método `getHttpGet` em uma thread que não seja a thread principal da aplicação. Para fazer isso, a forma mais fácil e óbvia seria [utilizar a clase `AsyncTask`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10416/132).